# How to create a jar file with gradle shadowJar that works on java 11

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I have java version 15 on my PC, and when I create a jar file with `gradle` using `gradle shadowJar`, the jar file does not run on my mac which has java version 11.

Here is my project setting, I have already changed the version to java 11 on the gradle setting page.

[image]

Here is the error on my mac:

[image]

Is there a quick way to fix this?

Comment: no screenshots of text please ..

Comment: So how did you build the jar? You say "using gradle", but then you post a screenshot of intellij project settings... so did you do it through intellij support for gradle, or using gradle directly?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are building on the command line and not through IntelliJ. Otherwise, I don't know what is wrong. But even if you are not, you should still configure Java compatibility to make your build more independent of the local environment.

Gradle will by default build with the same JDK as you run Gradle with. You can verify what version that is by `gradlew --version` on the command line. Normally you can set it with the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`.

In order to ensure your build is compatible with Java 11, no matter what version you use to run Gradle with, you have a few options.

Firstly, you can specify a toolchain. This will make Gradle automatically download a compatible version of the JDK if you are not already using one. Only available since Gradle 6.7.

```java
// Groovy DSL. Gradle 6.7+
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
}
```

You can also specify a release flag. This will instruct the current JDK, even if you are running with Java 15, to make the build compatible with an earlier version. Only available since Gradle version 6.6.

```java
// Groovy DSL. Gradle 6.6+
compileJava {
    options.release = 11
}
```

Lastly, if you are on an older version of Gradle, you can specify a source and target compatibility. This is not as good as the previous options as it doesn't ensure that you are using only Java 11 compatible APIs - only the bytecode will be compatible with Java 11.

```java
// Groovy DSL. Any version of Gradle (but not as safe)
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 11
    targetCompatibility = 11
}
```